# Search Issue in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, search-terms

I typed in **Plain Back** and I did not see any results for plain back until page 12.

Looks like it searched for **back** first and then gave me the results for **"plain back"** together.

I only want exact Plain Back should be search.

Current back end setting for search : 
Search Type = Fulltext

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the default magento search by:

1. Disabling the search option for most of the attributes and enabled those need only like sku and name.
2. Go to catalog > attributes > manage attributes > attribute name

   - Use in Quick Search >No
   - Use in Advanced Search->No